# AVG and AD-Aware system scan in multiple partitions?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, anti-virus

I have Win7 with AVG + AD-Aware installed running in a (C:)50gb NTFS partition and all Admin files e.g. Desktop, Documents, Music, Videos, Downloads etc.. are stored in a separate (D:)150gb NTFS partition.  Will AVG and Ad-Aware scan both partitions not just in (C:)? Or should I install both from (D:) as well and run a separate scan?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In most antivirus programs you can specify which drives are scanned. I have Avira installed, when I click System Scanner I am given the option of selecting exactly which drives are scanned. I'm sure you can do the same thing with AVG and AD-Aware.